# Zoho Catalyst Data Store, Functions - Unable to retrieve a row

Tags: serverless

I'm trying to get a row from datastore, while trying I've got the below error.I've included the script I'm trying.

Output:

```
{
    "status": "failure",
    "data": {
        "message": "basicio Execution Time Exceeded",
        "error_code": "EXECUTION_TIME_EXCEEDED"
    }
}
```

**Code Snippet :**

```
let rowData = 
    { 
        response: "George Hamilton",
    };
    const https = require("https");
    const axios = require("axios");
    const catalyst = require("zcatalyst-sdk-node");
    const app = catalyst.initialize(context);

    let datastore = app.datastore();
    let table = datastore.table('xxxx');
    let rowPromise = table.getRow(xxxxx);
        basicIO.write(rowPromise + "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Zoho Catalyst Basic IO functions will have an execution timeout of maximum of 30 seconds. Missing of proper exception handling might also lead to a timeout.  Enclose your code in a try catch block in order to catch the exceptions and you need to await in table.getRow() since it returns a promise and you have to resolve the promise by using .then().

```
let rowPromise = await table.getRow('xxxxx'); 
rowPromise.then((response) => {
console.log(response);
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
}).catch((err)=> {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err.toString());
})
```